# On click loads a different website but still within my website - like Facebook

Tags: html

On Facebook, via mobile, If you go to a profile page and click on a link to a person website it loads the website up in front of the Facebook website so when they press the X in the top left-hand corner it then deletes the webpage and the Facebook is still there.

On my desktop computer, I have used a different tap to load up but can't find out how I can do it this way for mobile and tablet?

I'm sure its quite simple but I have not got a clue what to look for sadly

Hope you can help, please.

Many Thanks

Tim

[image: Facebook profile page]
[image: click on link and load website via facebook]

Answer (score 0):

The picture you give appears to be the native mobile app for Facebook and not a webpage.

It just uses an embedded browser in the mobile app. How you do that depends on which platform you are developing for. For iOS it would be something along the lines of the [UIWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview) class.